# TO_DATE query on ArcSDE for Oracle dataset failing?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, enterprise-geodatabase, query, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to use TO_DATE to query an Oracle SDE dataset. It's not working in the javascript API application so I tried to query the rest end point directly and I get the error:

"Unable to perform query" on a java version of ArcGIS Server I also get the error "Please check your parameters"

Here is the ESRI topic at 10 which shows how to_date should be used 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000033000000.htm

The format:

```
Datefield = TO_DATE('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

My Query:

```
DateTest = TO_DATE('2012-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

I have also tried not including the time and using / instead of -

Oracle version is 10g. ArcGIS server is version 10 (.net and java tried)

Comment: Have you tried running the sql in a sqlplus window? i.e. select to_char(TO_DATE('2012-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) from dual; Does it return an error? It maybe something with your locale?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and recycling the application pool followed by a cache clear of the 10.0 rest fixed the problem. I believe I have to figure out how to configure my application pool better so these errors don't happen. That was the quick fix anyway.

Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: I'm off the project now but thanks for the suggestion. I will be sure to try it next time.

Comment: @DavidWilton Even though you are off the project now I think you should reward user1567453 by Accept-ing his/her Answer.  If when "next time" comes up you find it does not work then you can always un-Accept or move your Accept to another Answer.

Comment: I can't accept an answer I don't know is correct. Nobody else has upvoted the answer and nobody else has commented to say it worked. I haven't presently got a version of Java ArcGIS server I can test on